# Solve maze recursively using c++, cannot handle an exceptional case

Tags: c++

I am using an algorithm that I found online to solve a maze.

```
FIND-PATH(x, y)

if (x,y outside maze) return false
if (x,y is goal) return true
if (x,y not open) return false
mark x,y as part of solution path
if (FIND-PATH(North of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(East of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(South of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(West of x,y) == true) return true
unmark x,y as part of solution path
return false
```

The algorithm works good on most mazes. But it cannot handle an exception:

```
######
#s.  #
#.## #
#.####
#...f#
######
```

As shown in the picture, # is a wall, empty space is available path, s is the start and f is the finish.
And the '.' dotted line is the solution path marked after running the maze solving program.

In this case, the start point blocks the path into two way, and after running the program, there is one extra dot at the right side of the start point which cannot be unmarked.

I am wondering could anyone point out that why this happens to the above algorithm. And what extra check should I add to the solve() function? Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend debugging your code, to see what's going on in detail and how you may fix it.

Comment: I suggest using dfs, don't visit visited nodes again. Check this condition in begining

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your advice. The code works OK on other mazes if the start point does not block the path into two isolated ways. I have tried to add some checks to address the issue, but none of them works so far. I will keep trying : )

Comment: can you paste the actual code? it might reveal more clues... as the code is ok. btw: the first line is not needed if `S` is guranteed to be in the maze...

Comment: How are you checking for open path, that is important for debuging

Comment: Unrelated to C++_______________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is occurring because you are revisiting already visited node.

Consider you are at the extra dot you are considering at beginning of function. Now on your west side you might have missed checking if it is a start point, and considering start point as not outside maze and available path. So now the program again starts checking from start and thus giving false positive result.

Without actual code its hard to debug though.

**EDIT:** It suffers from exact problem is was talking about above

Do you know where start point is. If so do following

Replace

```
if (ch =='.' || ch == '#')
         return false;
```

with

```
if (ch =='.' || ch == '#' || ch=='s')
         return false;
```

Comment: I have tried to do it this way, but it turns out the the solution does not print at all. because it starts from the s point, I guess it returns false immediately?

Comment: But you basically understand the problem as I have described? My suggestion use DFS.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't get what u mean previously. Could you tell me what is DFS?

Comment: Yes please. I am a beginner in c++. So really like to know more.

Comment: @TejasPatel FYI You can always edit your answer to post more relevant information.